# How to detect if an editor is a markdown preview?

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Command `markdown.showSource` shows the source code of a markdown preview, how to write the `When` condition so that `markdown.showSource` only triggers when the active editor is indeed a markdown preview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"when": "markdownPreviewFocus"`

How did I find this? (With a markdown preview editor open)

1. Toggle the Help/Developer Tools On, go to its console.
2. Start the command [`Developer: Inspect Context Keys`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts#inspect-context-keys-utility)

I just clicked anywhere in vscode. In the developer tools console, you will get a long list of active context keys. I searched for `preview` and there were a few but this one looked really promising and it worked!

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice pro tip, I've added a reference link for that. And `markdownPreviewFocus` is also mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/0d584a908611a819db0167c26028419cd08830d6/extensions/markdown-language-features/package.json#L91).

Answer (score 0):

Now it's been updated to `"when": "activeWebviewPanelId == 'markdown.preview' || activeCustomEditorId == 'vscode.markdown.preview.editor'"`, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/055458feab40fc308fc6d70b185068138c8cf8eb/extensions/markdown-language-features/package.json#L205) for an example.